# no rule to process file of type image.png for architecture i386

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I.m trying to create Pod for Cocoapods. And during podspec validation got this error:

```
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.
- NOTE  | xcodebuild:  warning: no rule to process file 'sequencing-file-selector-api-objc/Pod/ResourceBundle.bundle/myfiles.png' of type image.png for architecture i386
- NOTE  | xcodebuild:  warning: no rule to process file 'sequencing-file-selector-api-objc/Pod/ResourceBundle.bundle/nav_clear_pixel.png' of type image.png for architecture i386
- NOTE  | xcodebuild:  warning: no rule to process file 'sequencing-file-selector-api-objc/Pod/ResourceBundle.bundle/nav_pixel.png' of type image.png for architecture i386
- NOTE  | xcodebuild:  warning: no rule to process file 'sequencing-file-selector-api-objc/Pod/ResourceBundle.bundle/samplefiles.png' of type image.png for architecture i386
- NOTE  | xcodebuild:  warning: no rule to process file 'sequencing-file-selector-api-objc/Pod/ResourceBundle.bundle/myfiles.png' of type image.png for architecture x86_64
- NOTE  | xcodebuild:  warning: no rule to process file 'sequencing-file-selector-api-objc/Pod/ResourceBundle.bundle/nav_clear_pixel.png' of type image.png for architecture x86_64
- NOTE  | xcodebuild:  warning: no rule to process file 'sequencing-file-selector-api-objc/Pod/ResourceBundle.bundle/nav_pixel.png' of type image.png for architecture x86_64
- NOTE  | xcodebuild:  warning: no rule to process file 'sequencing-file-selector-api-objc/Pod/ResourceBundle.bundle/samplefiles.png' of type image.png for architecture x86_64
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  : error: Not enough arguments provided; where is the input document to operate on?
```

Podspec contains following settings:

```
s.resource = 'Pod/ResourceBundle.bundle'
s.resources = ['Pod/ResourceBundle.bundle/*.png']
```

All images are within `ResourceBundle.bundle` file

How to handle such error? Can't validate podspec.

Comment: Looks like you trying to compile png files, please look at xcode configuration and remove all png file form source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I found out the problem was that I did'n specified resources files as a actually `Resources` (.png, .storyboard, and .xib) while creating CocoaPod.

So I created a `Resources` folder within the pod and moved all `png` images, custom `storyboard` file and `xib` files.

In `podspec` file I added following specification:

```
s.resources = ['Resources/**/*.*']
```

As a result `podspec` file was validated successfully and I was able to release the pod.